# ASP.NET Core JWT Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt

A bit new on JWT but I am working on a .NET MVC Project (it is not a Web API). I wanted to implement JWT tokens but every article online shows it for SPA where the token is passed via HTTP Request in the Authorization Header. I have a few questions

1. I am unsure in MVC how to persist the token from request to response? Should we store the token in a cookie on the response or is there a place that is standard to store it?
2. Is there a way on the response to add it to the Http Response Header Auth (although I think this is done on the Http Request instead on the client side so I might be wrong in this).
3. On the server, where should we store it (session? db table?)
4. If I configure my startup middleware to add JWT Authentication, how does the request pipeline handle this (it goes back to question 2 since there will be no Bearer token attached on the Http Request). The code below won't execute.

[image]

Essentially, I want to achieve what SPA projects can do somehow with sending the JWT token in the Http Header Auth but I haven't seen much on MVC projects.

Comment: Perhaps the question to start out with is: why do you want to use JWT? What does token authentication give you that e.g. cookie based authentication can't provide?

Comment: I have an exposed API as part of the same solution to do testing with. So the tests need to generate a token which I understand but I guess if I already have the tests using that, why not also have the same logic for the MVC side. It's just I'm not sure how to achieve this on the MVC side

Comment: I think that the best way is to protect your MVC routes with a cookie based auth (MVC style) and use a JWT or ApiKey auth on your "exposed to do testing API". You can configure that by specifying the authentication schema inside `Auhtorize` attribute once authentications are set up.

Comment: @ale91 this is the route I chose - cookie auth for the mvc and jwt for the api. I can't seem to get both schemes working though

Comment: @SomeDev can you post an example of the code that seems not working?

Comment: @ale91 I made another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071111/asp-net-core-two-authentication-schemes-jwt-cookieauth