# ASP.NET Core Two Authentication Schemes (JWT + CookieAuth)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, jwt

I have an MVC web app and an exposed API that I want to use cookieauth for the web app and JWT for the exposed API. I am testing the API and it always seems to default to the cookie auth handler in the middleware for some reason.

Below in the startup, I added two event handlers just to test breakpoints and the API hits the cookie event handler instead of the JWT handler. I specify the scheme in the action so not really sure why it's not working.

Startup.cs Configure Services

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Index";
            options.LoginPath = "/Login/Login";
            options.Cookie.Name = "CookieAuthentication";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = e =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        { 
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtIssuer") ?? Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtIssuer") ?? Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtKey") ?? Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
            };
            options.Events.OnChallenge = e =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
    }
}
```

StartUp Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

As an example, I do this with my API and doesn't hit the correct scheme in the startup

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult Foo()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to register 2 auth scheme like that:

```cs
    //Cookie
    _ = services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Index";
        options.LoginPath = "/Login/Login";
        options.Cookie.Name = "CookieAuthentication";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = e =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

    //Jwt
    _ = services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtIssuer") ?? Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtIssuer") ?? Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JwtKey") ?? Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
            };
            options.Events.OnChallenge = e =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

And decorate your actions with the auth scheme you need:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult Foo()
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public IActionResult FooCookie()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

EDIT:
Use a base controller to make authentication inheritance (attribute can be inherited):

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class MyJwtBaseController : ApiController
{

}
```

If you want to unauthorize a specific action:

```cs
public class MyController : MyJwtBaseController 
{
   public IActionResult Foo()  //Inherits base controller auth
   {
       return Ok();
   }

   [AllowAnonymous]
   public IActionResult FooUnauthorize()  //No auth
   {
       return Ok();
   }
}
```

Comment: I've been stuck on this for a week haha it was simply registering each (and I was combining it). This work now thanks a lot!

Comment: Wondering is there a way to have a default? I'd prefer Cookie so I only have to update the API actions only.

Comment: @SomeDev I have edited my answer: you can use base controllers

Comment: I'm having an issue - how can I configure it so that the API doesn't use the CookieAuth middleware? It seems that when I make an API call, it defaults to the CookieAuth. It seems like the param being passed in AddAuthentication overrides whatever we do in the first call.

Comment: I think you have to delete default options inside add cookie auth, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I don't think that fixes it - it seems you just override it the second time (meaning JWT is the default scheme now). If I put the the code for cookie logic below, it seems to work and vice versa.